# Generate mongo database view combining fields from 3 collections using mongo DB query

Tags: jquery, mongodb, view, lookup

I need to write a mongo query to create a mongo DB view (`USER`) using different fields from 3 collections (`EMPLOYEE`, `ROLE`, and `GROUP` ).

- `EMPLOYEE` collection contains employeeName, roleId, and groupId
- `ROLE` collection contains id and roleName `GROUP` collection
- `GROUP` collection contains id and groupName

The final creating view which is called `USER` should contain `employeeName`, `roleName`, and `groupName`

I have managed to build the query combining 2 collections (`EMPLOYEE` and `ROLE`) and having issues merging the 3rd Group collection to this.

```
db.createView (
   "USER",
   "EMPLOYEE",
   [
     { $lookup: { from: "ROLE", localField: "roleId", foreignField: "id", as: "roleName" } },
     { $project: { employeeName: 1, roleName: 1}}
   ]
)
```

How we can combine the 3rd `GROUP` collection here with the lookup for group id. Any help will be appreciated.

Sample JSON data is given below

```
Employee

[{
  "_id": {
    "$oid": "5f8943d5ebd92d68b696ce00"
  },
  "employeeName": "ABC",
  "roleId": {
    "$oid": "5f8943d5ebd92d68b696ce12"
  },
  "groupId": {
    "$oid": "5f8943d5ebd92d68b696ce42"
  }
},{
  "_id": {
    "$oid": "5f8943d5ebd92d68b696ce74"
  },
  "employeeName": "PQR",
  "roleId": {
    "$oid": "5f8943d5ebd92d68b696ce48"
  },
  "groupId": {
    "$oid": "5f8943d5ebd42d68b696ce31"
  }
}]
```

=================================

```
Role

[{
  "_id": {
    "$oid": "5f8943d5ebd92d68b696ce12"
  },
  "roleName": "Admin"
},{
  "_id": {
    "$oid": "5f8943d5ebd92d68b696ce48"
  },
  "roleName": "Support"
}]
```

===================================

```
Group

[{
  "_id": {
    "$oid": "5f8943d5ebd92d68b696ce42"
  },
  "roleName": "group1"
},{
  "_id": {
    "$oid": "5f8943d5ebd42d68b696ce31"
  },
  "roleName": "group2"
}]
```

Comment: please provide sample JSON data for all three collections (employee, role and group)

Comment: updated the sample JSON data

Comment: Can you please let me know approx? count of documents in each of your collection current and future. since MongoDB is "no SQL" unlike relational DB, one would be better to store data into one or two collections. unless your data is increasing exponentially eg. tweets. in that case, you can look at another collection. Further in your case is it possible to Merge all your three collections into one master collection of Employee(having both Role and groups defined in the same document)

Answer (score 0):

Please try the option where you have two views created and link them up. Complete code below.

```
> db.Employee.find().pretty();
{
        "_id" : {
                "oid" : "5f8943d5ebd92d68b696ce00"
        },
        "employeeName" : "ABC",
        "roleId" : {
                "oid" : "5f8943d5ebd92d68b696ce12"
        },
        "groupId" : {
                "oid" : "5f8943d5ebd92d68b696ce42"
        }
}
{
        "_id" : {
                "oid" : "5f8943d5ebd92d68b696ce74"
        },
        "employeeName" : "PQR",
        "roleId" : {
                "oid" : "5f8943d5ebd92d68b696ce48"
        },
        "groupId" : {
                "oid" : "5f8943d5ebd42d68b696ce31"
        }
}
> db.Role.find().pretty()
{ "_id" : { "oid" : "5f8943d5ebd92d68b696ce12" }, "roleName" : "Admin" }
{ "_id" : { "oid" : "5f8943d5ebd92d68b696ce48" }, "roleName" : "Support" }
> db.Group.find().pretty();
{ "_id" : { "oid" : "5f8943d5ebd92d68b696ce42" }, "groupName" : "group1" }
{ "_id" : { "oid" : "5f8943d5ebd42d68b696ce31" }, "groupName" : "group2" }
> db.empRolesMap.drop();
true
> db.createView(
...   "empRolesMap",
...   "Employee",
...    [
...      {$lookup:{from: "Role",
...                localField: "roleId",
...                foreignField: "_id",
...                as : "empRoles"}
...       },
...       {$unwind:"$empRoles"},
...       {$project:{employeeName:1, "empRoles.roleName":1,groupId:1}}
...    ]
... );
{ "ok" : 1 }
> db.empRolesMap.find().pretty();
{
        "_id" : {
                "oid" : "5f8943d5ebd92d68b696ce00"
        },
        "employeeName" : "ABC",
        "groupId" : {
                "oid" : "5f8943d5ebd92d68b696ce42"
        },
        "empRoles" : {
                "roleName" : "Admin"
        }
}
{
        "_id" : {
                "oid" : "5f8943d5ebd92d68b696ce74"
        },
        "employeeName" : "PQR",
        "groupId" : {
                "oid" : "5f8943d5ebd42d68b696ce31"
        },
        "empRoles" : {
                "roleName" : "Support"
        }
}
>
>      db.empRolesGroupsMap.drop();
true
> db.createView(
...   "empRolesGroupsMap",
...    "empRolesMap",
...     [
...      {$lookup:{from: "Group",
...                localField: "groupId",
...                foreignField: "_id",
...                as: "empGroups"
...                }
...        },
...        {$unwind:"$empGroups"},
...        {$project:{employeeName:1,
...                   "empRoles.roleName":1,
...                   "empGroups.groupName":1,
...                   "_id":0}}
...      ]
...      );
{ "ok" : 1 }
> db.empRolesGroupsMap.find().pretty();
{
        "employeeName" : "ABC",
        "empRoles" : {
                "roleName" : "Admin"
        },
        "empGroups" : {
                "groupName" : "group1"
        }
}
{
        "employeeName" : "PQR",
        "empRoles" : {
                "roleName" : "Support"
        },
        "empGroups" : {
                "groupName" : "group2"
        }
}
> print("MongoDB",db.version());
MongoDB 4.4.1
```